# Multi-linearity of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set $S = \{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R^3} : \det A = 0\}$, where $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. How do we show it is a subspace and find its dimension? For example I thought I could use multi-linearity of determinants to show its a subspace but I'm not sure how the proof would look like to be complete. Also with multi-linearity, I'm not a 100% sure i understand it correctly. This is what I understood for multi-linearity  $$ \det \begin{pmatrix} c_1a & c_2b & c_3c \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} = c_1 \det \begin{pmatrix} a & c_2b & c_3c \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} + c_2 \det \begin{pmatrix} c_1a & b & c_3c \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} + c_3\det \begin{pmatrix} c_1a & c_2b & c \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

This doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Outline:

Note that $\det A=-(b-c)$. So your set is rewritten as $$\{(a,b,c) \in \Bbb R^3: b-c=0\}$$

This set is just the homogeneous solution of $Ax=0$ where $A= \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c\end{pmatrix}^t$, which is clearly a subspace of dimension $2!$

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of multilinearity is incorrect. For the context of this problem, the important thing to understand is that for vectors $(a_1,b_1,c_1),(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ and scalars $k_1,k_2$, we have
$$
\det \pmatrix{k_1 a_1 + k_2 a_2 & k_1b_1 + k_2 b_2 & k_1c_1 + k_2 c_2\\
1&1&1\\
0&1&1} =\\
k_1\cdot \det \pmatrix{a_1& b_1& c_1\\
1&1&1\\
0&1&1} + 
k_2 \cdot \det
\pmatrix{a_2 & b_2 & c_2\\
1&1&1\\
0&1&1}.
$$
More generally: if $v,w$ are (constant) row vectors and $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is a row-vector, then the function $T:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$
T(x) = \det \pmatrix{x\\v\\w}
$$
is linear. This is true for each of the rows of the determinant, which is to say that the functions
$$
x \mapsto \det \pmatrix{v\\x\\w}, \quad x \mapsto \det \pmatrix{v\\w\\x}
$$
are also linear. The fact that all these maps are linear is what is meant by the "multilinearity" of the determinant.